# How to get optimality gap using CPLEX Python API?

Tags: python-2.7, cplex

How can the optimality gap (relative and absolute) be obtained using CPLEX Python API (CPLEX 12.5, Python 2.7.15)? Is there any function such as `get_optimal_gap()` that would give the optimality gap? Or is parsing the output (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832501/how-to-get-value-of-elapsed-time-after-using-cplex-python-api?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) the only way? I see that there are custom functions such as `solution.get_objective_value()` - it would be nice if someone can suggest online resources that have a list of all functions that can be applied on the cplex object/file. Currently I am using the following code (courtesy: [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27042869&aid=1) IBM document):

```
    import cplex
    import sys

    def sample1(filename):
        c = cplex.Cplex(filename)
        try:
            c.solve()
        except CplexSolverError:
            print "Exception raised during solve"
            return

        # solution.get_status() returns an integer code
        status = c.solution.get_status()
        print "Solution status = " , status, ":",
        print c.solution.status[status]
        print "Objective value = " , c.solution.get_objective_value()

    sample1(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the CPLEX Python API is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html) (currently version 12.8).

To get the relative mip gap, you can use [c.solution.MIP.get_mip_relative_gap()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.MIPSolutionInterface-class.html#get_mip_relative_gap). To calculate the absolute mip gap you'll need [c.solution.MIP.get_best_objective()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.MIPSolutionInterface-class.html#get_best_objective).

If you haven't already, you'll also want to take a look at the [CPX_PARAM_EPGAP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpAGap.html) and [CPX_PARAM_EPAGAP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpGap.html) parameters.

Comment: This is great, thank you! The documentation is fantastic!